# Kali 2.0 DSL connection

Tags: networking, kali-linux, networkmanager, network-interface

I have freshly installed Kali 2.0 but I don't know to how to get access to the Internet by using my Username and Password.

Can anyone tell me how to configure manually Ethernet(eth0) or rather DSL/PPPOE?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't need any especial configuration just plug the cable and use the configured modem in case of DSL.
in network connection add new connection DSL then enter your user password and select the automatic PPPOE apply it and that's it!